# Trouble posting to connected WebSocket client from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement Websockets using AWS API Gateway and Lambda.

I am using wscat on the command line to test the WebSocket.

I am able to create a connection and save the connection info when the client connects and I am able to retrieve the connection info when I need to send data to the connected client, but when I try to POST data to the connected client the lambda times out (`Task timed out after 10.01 seconds`). Here is the code I am using to POST to the connected client.

```
const apiGateway = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi(
{
  apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
  endpoint: xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com + '/' + stage
 });

console.log("Trying to post");

const params = 
{
     ConnectionId: currentConnection.connection_id,
     Data: `Test post`
 };

 await apiGateway.postToConnection(params, function(error, data){
       if (error) console.log(error, error.stack); // an error occurred
        else      console.log(data);           // successful response
 }).promise();;
```

When this bit of code runs, I do not see anything on the terminal where I have the WebSocket connection using wscat.

I can see the "Trying to post" console log from just before the call to `postToConnection` and then nothing. I am assuming it is the call to `postToConnection` thats causing the timeout.

How do I POST data to a connected client using AWS WebSockets from a Lambda?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/serverless-websockets-with-aws-lambda-fanout-15384bd30354